# BeautifulSoup innerhtml?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, innerhtml

Let's say I have a page with a `div`. I can easily get that div with `soup.find()`.

Now that I have the result, I'd like to print the WHOLE `innerhtml` of that `div`: I mean, I'd need a string with ALL the html tags and text all toegether, exactly like the string I'd get in javascript with `obj.innerHTML`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 105):

## TL;DR

With BeautifulSoup 4 use `element.encode_contents()` if you want a UTF-8 encoded bytestring or use `element.decode_contents()` if you want a Python Unicode string. For example the [DOM's innerHTML method](http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#innerhtml) might look something like this:

```py
def innerHTML(element):
    """Returns the inner HTML of an element as a UTF-8 encoded bytestring"""
    return element.encode_contents()
```

---

These functions aren't currently in the online documentation so I'll quote the current function definitions and the doc string from the code.

## `encode_contents` - since 4.0.4

```py
def encode_contents(
    self, indent_level=None, encoding=DEFAULT_OUTPUT_ENCODING,
    formatter="minimal"):
    """Renders the contents of this tag as a bytestring.

    :param indent_level: Each line of the rendering will be
       indented this many spaces.

    :param encoding: The bytestring will be in this encoding.

    :param formatter: The output formatter responsible for converting
       entities to Unicode characters.
    """
```

See also the [documentation on formatters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters); you'll most likely either use `formatter="minimal"` (the default) or `formatter="html"` (for [html entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity)) unless you want to manually process the text in some way.

`encode_contents` returns an encoded bytestring. If you want a Python Unicode string then use `decode_contents` instead.

---

## `decode_contents` - since 4.0.1

`decode_contents` does the same thing as `encode_contents` but returns a Python Unicode string instead of an encoded bytestring.

```py
def decode_contents(self, indent_level=None,
                   eventual_encoding=DEFAULT_OUTPUT_ENCODING,
                   formatter="minimal"):
    """Renders the contents of this tag as a Unicode string.

    :param indent_level: Each line of the rendering will be
       indented this many spaces.

    :param eventual_encoding: The tag is destined to be
       encoded into this encoding. This method is _not_
       responsible for performing that encoding. This information
       is passed in so that it can be substituted in if the
       document contains a <META> tag that mentions the document's
       encoding.

    :param formatter: The output formatter responsible for converting
       entities to Unicode characters.
    """
```

---

## BeautifulSoup 3

BeautifulSoup 3 doesn't have the above functions, instead it has `renderContents`

```py
def renderContents(self, encoding=DEFAULT_OUTPUT_ENCODING,
                   prettyPrint=False, indentLevel=0):
    """Renders the contents of this tag as a string in the given
    encoding. If encoding is None, returns a Unicode string.."""
```

This function was added back to BeautifulSoup 4 ([in 4.0.4](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~arthur-darcet/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup/revision/206#bs4/element.py)) for compatibility with BS3.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @peewhy's answer does not work for the reasons ChrisD outlined.

Comment: Anyone know why this is undocumented? Seems like it would be a common use case.

Answer (score 17):

One of the options could be use something like that:

```
 innerhtml = "".join([str(x) for x in div_element.contents])
```

Comment: There are a few other problems with this. Firstly it doesn't escape html entities (such as greater than and less than) within string elements. Secondly, it will write the content of comments but not the comment tags itself.

Comment: Adding another reason not to use this to  @ChrisD comments: This will  throw a UnicodeDecodeError on content that includes non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 17):

Given a BS4 soup element like `<div id="outer"><div id="inner">foobar</div></div>`, here are some various methods and attributes that can be used to retrieve its HTML and text in different ways along with an example of what they'll return.

---

**InnerHTML:**

```py
inner_html = element.encode_contents()

'<div id="inner">foobar</div>'
```

**OuterHTML:**

```py
outer_html = str(element)

'<div id="outer"><div id="inner">foobar</div></div>'
```

**OuterHTML (prettified)**:

```py
pretty_outer_html = element.prettify()

'''<div id="outer">
 <div id="inner">
  foobar
 </div>
</div>'''
```

**Text only (using .text):**

```py
element_text = element.text

'foobar'
```

**Text only (using .string):**

```py
element_string = element.string

'foobar'
```

Answer (score 3):

`str(element)` helps you to get **outerHTML**, then remove outer tag from  the outer html string.

Comment: How do you remove outer tag from the outer html string?

Answer (score 1):

How about just `unicode(x)`? Seems to work for me.

**Edit:** This will give you the outer HTML and not the inner.

Comment: This will return the div including the outer element, not just the contents.

Comment: You're right. Leaving this here for now in case this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If I do not misunderstand, you mean that for an example like this:

```html
<div class="test">
    text in body
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

the output should de look like this:

```html
text in body
    <p>Hello World!</p>
```

So here is your answer:

```py
''.join(map(str,tag.contents))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the children property.

```
inner_html = soup.find('body').children
```

it will return a list. So, you can get the full code using a simple for loop.

```
for html in inner_html:
    print(html)
```

Comment: to get back content : `"".join(map(str,soup.find('body').children)).strip()`

Answer (score -4):

## For just text, Beautiful Soup 4 `get_text()`

If you only want the human-readable text inside a document or tag, you can use the `get_text()` method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string:

```
markup = '<a href="http://example.com/">\nI linked to <i>example.com</i>\n</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser')

soup.get_text()
'\nI linked to example.com\n'
soup.i.get_text()
'example.com'
```

You can specify a string to be used to join the bits of text together:

```
soup.get_text("|")
'\nI linked to |example.com|\n'
```

You can tell Beautiful Soup to strip whitespace from the beginning and end of each bit of text:

```
soup.get_text("|", strip=True)
'I linked to|example.com'
```

But at that point you might want to use the `.stripped_strings` generator instead, and process the text yourself:

```
[text for text in soup.stripped_strings]
# ['I linked to', 'example.com']
```

As of Beautiful Soup version 4.9.0, when `lxml` or `html.parser` are in use, the contents of `<script>`, `<style>`, and `<template>` tags are not considered to be `‘text’`, since those tags are not part of the human-visible content of the page.

Refer here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Comment: ...was the question a different question at some point?

Comment: @Driftr95 It's been a while and tbh I forgot.