# Saving <br/> in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm creating parser, and i have following construction:

```
quotes = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'text'})
```

But it's strip all html tags(like br). How I can change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`findAll` itself will give you a list of HTML nodes.

If you want to retrieve their text content (without tags), use [`.get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

To get the children of these nodes (as objects too), use [`.contents` or `.children`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children).

In order to print a node's children as a well-formatted string, you can use [`.prettify()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing). Note that this won't exactly preserve the original formatting.

See also:
 [BeautifulSoup innerhtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112922/beautifulsoup-innerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take out the tags from the text, you could try something like this:

```
for item in quotes:
  quote = re.sub(r"\<.*?\>", "", quote)
```

Comment: No, on the contrary, I want to save all the tags
May be my English is terrible, i'm sorry for it:)

Comment: No problem, so do you want to convert the tags to "\n" or?