# Don't put html, head and body tags automatically, beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html5lib

I'm using beautifulsoup with html5lib, it puts the `html`, `head` and `body` tags automatically:

```
BeautifulSoup('<h1>FOO</h1>', 'html5lib') # => <html><head></head><body><h1>FOO</h1></body></html>
```

Is there any option that I can set, turn off this behavior ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you're trying to parse it as a fragment of a document (like `innerHTML` does), then you want a different API.

Comment: I created a feature request to update the docs. This issue should be explained in the porting docs. Feature Request: https://bugs.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/+bug/1370364 Porting docs: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
In [35]: import bs4 as bs

In [36]: bs.BeautifulSoup('<h1>FOO</h1>', "html.parser")
Out[36]: <h1>FOO</h1>
```

This [parses the HTML with Python's builtin HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).
Quoting the docs:

> Unlike html5lib, this parser makes no attempt to create a well-formed
> HTML document by adding a `<body>` tag. Unlike lxml, it doesn’t even
> bother to add an `<html>` tag.

---

Alternatively, you could use the `html5lib` parser and just select the element after `<body>`:

```
In [61]: soup = bs.BeautifulSoup('<h1>FOO</h1>', 'html5lib')

In [62]: soup.body.next
Out[62]: <h1>FOO</h1>
```

Comment: Note that this response is actually broken in case of multiple elements within the body. If you would have `<h1>a</h1><h1>b</h1>` it would only return `<h1>a</h1>`

Comment: One can do "soup.html.hidden=True (;) soup.head.hidden=True (;) soup.body.hidden=True" before printing and you get the desired result.  Humongously inefficient, though, if you're iterating through a lot of cells in a table.

Comment: `soup.body.next` grabs the next element in the body, as the name suggests: Is there a way to grab everything inside the body "as is" (that is, not as text)? In other words, grab the complement of `soup.body.decompose()` Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to throw this out there: `body = soup.find('body')` and `body.findChildren(recursive=False)[0]` (I had no luck with `.unwrap()`)

Comment: @Wolph: then use the `children` generator and join the output? `"".join(map(str, soup.body.children))`.

Comment: @PatrickT: Use [`soup.body.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children), which is a list of direct descendants (including text nodes). Or use `iter(soup.body)` and iterate over that. Or use `list(soup.body)` to produce a list of the direct descending nodes. They are all the same thing, really; `list()` and `iter()` call the `__iter__` method, and the `__iter__` method returns `iter(self.contents)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think it's just `soup.children` in this case. Unless you're parsing a full document you won't have a `body`

Comment: @Wolph: you may want to read the question ;-) The whole *point* of the question is that a `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tag have been added. That's because BeautifulSoup deals with whole documents, not with fragments, and `html5lib` (and `lxml` too, by the way) repair broken HTML documents by adding the required but missing elements back in.

Comment: @Wolph I don't get the same result...

Answer (score 8):

This aspect of BeautifulSoup has always annoyed the hell out of me.

Here's how I deal with it:

```
# Parse the initial html-formatted string
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# Do stuff here

# Extract a string repr of the parse html object, without the <html> or <body> tags
html = "".join([str(x) for x in soup.body.children])
```

A quick breakdown:

```
# Iterator object of all tags within the <body> tag (your html before parsing)
soup.body.children

# Turn each element into a string object, rather than a BS4.Tag object
# Note: inclusive of html tags
str(x)

# Get a List of all html nodes as string objects
[str(x) for x in soup.body.children]

# Join all the string objects together to recreate your original html
"".join()
```

I still don't like this, but it gets the job done. I always run into this when I use BS4 to filter certain elements and/or attributes from HTML documents before doing something else with them where I need the entire object back as a string repr rather than a BS4 parsed object.

Hopefully, the next time I Google this, I'll find my answer here.

Comment: This worked fine. The other answer with findChildren() seem to discard text directly inside the body and not in another tag.

Comment: There's an undocumented function `decode_contents()` now, see my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62820810/237105), which is aimed to stop the annoyance I also had before.

Comment: Why does it annoy you? Because BeautifulSoup is designed to deal with HTML documents, not fragments? Note that your approach gives a string, not a BeautifulSoup object tree.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It annoys me in situations where a fragment is parsed and the `html` and `body` tags are added to it, by default. WRT to the `str` vs BS4 parse object; did you feel my post didn't draw attention to that appropriately at the bottom?

Comment: You did, but the question never mentioned needing just the string.

Answer (score 7):

Let's first create a soup sample:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup("<head></head><body><p>content</p></body>")
```

You could get html and body's child by specify `soup.body.<tag>`:

```
# python3: get body's first child
print(next(soup.body.children))

# if first child's tag is rss
print(soup.body.rss)
```

Also you could use **unwrap()** to remove body, head, and html

```
soup.html.body.unwrap()
if soup.html.select('> head'):
    soup.html.head.unwrap()
soup.html.unwrap()
```

If you load xml file, `bs4.diagnose(data)` will tell you to use `lxml-xml`, which will not wrap your soup with `html+body`

```
>>> BS('<foo>xxx</foo>', 'lxml-xml')
<foo>xxx</foo>
```

Comment: `soup.html.unwrap()` then `soup.body.unwrap()` worked for me!

Comment: No, parsing a document as XML will indeed not add required HTML elements. But treating HTML as XML introduces other issues, because XML is not HTML. Like in HTML, the tags `<H1>` and `<h1>` are the same thing, but in XML, where tag names are case-sensitive, they are not. So `<H1>Foo</h1>` is valid HTML, but not valid XML.

Answer (score 4):

You may have misunderstood BeautifulSoup here. BeautifulSoup deals with **whole HTML documents**, not with HTML **fragments**. What you see is ***by design***.

Without a `<html>` and `<body>` tag, your HTML document is broken. BeautifulSoup leaves it to the specific parser to repair such a document, and different parsers differ in how much they *can* repair. `html5lib` is the most thorough of the parsers, but you'll get similar results with the `lxml` parser (but `lxml` leaves out the `<head>` tag). The `html.parser` parser is the least capable, it can do *some* repair work but it doesn't add back required but missing tags.

So this is a deliberate feature of the `html5lib` library, it *fixes* HTML that is lacking, such as adding back in missing required elements.

There is not option for BeautifulSoup to treat the HTML you pass in as a fragment. **At most** you can 'break' the document and remove the `<html>` and `<body>` elements again with the standard BeautifulSoup tree manipulation methods.

E.g. using [`Element.replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) lets you replace the `html` element with your `<h1>` element:

```py
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<h1>FOO</h1>', 'html5lib')
>>> soup
<html><head></head><body><h1>FOO</h1></body></html>
>>> soup.html.replace_with(soup.body.contents[0])
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
>>> soup
<h1>FOO</h1>
```

Take into account however, that `html5lib` can add *other* elements to your tree too, such as `tbody` elements:

```py
>>> BeautifulSoup(
...     '<table><tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr></table>', 'html5lib'
... ).table
<table><tbody><tr><td>Foo</td><td>Bar</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The HTML standard states that a table should always have a `<tbody>` element, and if it is missing, a parser should treat the document as if the element is there anyway. `html5lib` follows the standard very, very closely.

Comment: But if the data isn't meant to be a complete HTML document, it's not missing at all.

Comment: @KefSchecter: `html5lib` expects complete HTML documents, not HTML fragments. So whatever the data was _meant_ to be, `html5lib` is not the library to use for HTML fragments. Hell, BeautifulSoup is not the library to use, a BeautifulSoup object expects to handle complete documents, but it's up to the parser to repair things if not.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Hello <a href="http://google.com">Google</a></p><p>Hi!</p>', 'lxml')
# content handling example (just for example)
# replace Google with StackOverflow
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
  a['href'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/'
  a.string = 'StackOverflow'
print ''.join([unicode(i) for i in soup.html.body.findChildren(recursive=False)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
html=str(soup)
html=html.replace("<html><body>","")
html=html.replace("</body></html>","")
```

will remove the html/body tag bracket. A more sophisticated version would also check for startsWith, endsWith ...

Comment: Why string replacement? Why not just use `str(soup.body.contents[0])` (for single-element bodies, or use looping and `str.join()`) or  even simpler, `soup.body.decode_contents()`? The latter is, unfortunately, not documented but is the method that `Element.decode()` calls to render the contents when rendering itself, and `Element.decode()` is the base implementation for `__str__`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to look better, try this:

> BeautifulSoup([contents you want to analyze]**.prettify()**)

Answer (score -1):

Since v4.0.1 there's a method `decode_contents()`:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup('<h1>FOO</h1>', 'html5lib').body.decode_contents()
'<h1>FOO</h1>'
```

More details in a solution to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602241/237105

**Update:**

As rightfully noted by @MartijnPieters in the comments this way you'll still get some extra tags like `tbody` (in the tables) which you might or might not want.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question though. Note that if you passed in a snippet with a table but no `tbody` tag, you'll find that `html5lib` has added one; `'<table><tr><td>Foo</td></tr></table>'` -> `'<html><head></head><body><table><tbody><tr><td>Foo</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>'`, and that might be unexpected too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it might be unexpected, but it does answer the question. OP said nothing about `tbody`.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: nor do they ask about getting the contents as a string: *Is there any option that I can set, turn off this behavior ?* is what they asked.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're not reading it carefully enough: "it puts the html, head and body tags automatically" - this is the behavior they want to turn off.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins: I've read it just fine. Which is why I pointed out that there are other tags that are added automatically, not just those observed by the OP. Your solution doesn't turn those 'off'. Nor is it stated that the OP wanted a string. Maybe they wanted a BeautifulSoup object without those tags?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's a useful addition, thanks. Yet it does not make the answer better or worse as it is not something OP originally asked for. He might as well be pleased with the addition of `tbody` tags. "Maybe they wanted a BeautifulSoup object without those tags?" - or maybe not. We do not know for sure. In the meanwhile maybe another reader is interested in strings particularly.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I do it

```
a = BeautifulSoup()
a.append(a.new_tag('section'))
#this will give you <section></section>
```