# How to prevent BeautifulSoup4 from adding extra <html><body> tags to the soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In BeautifulSoup versions prior to 3 I could take any chunk of HTML and get a string representation in this way:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup3 = BeautifulSoup('<div><b>soup 3</b></div>')
print unicode(soup3)
    '<div><b>soup</b></div>'
```

However with BeautifulSoup4 the same operation creates additional tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup4 = BeautifulSoup('<div><b>soup 4</b></div>')
print unicode(soup4)
    '<html><body><div><b>soup 4</b></div></body></html>'
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't need the outer **`<html><body>..</body></html>`** tags that BS4 is adding. I have looked through the BS4 docs and also searched inside the class but could not find any setting for supressing the extra tags in the output. How do I do it? Downgrading to v3 is not an option since the SGML parser used in BS3 is not near as good as the `lxml` or `html5lib` parsers that are available with BS4.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14822188/57318 I think?

Comment: @Xymostech Yes, but the proposed solution in that question is to change the parser which imho is not the best option. For example, because `lxml` is really cool.. Apparently what i need to do is `soup2.html.body.contents[0]` but is there a nicer option?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that actually changes which parser it uses. Hmm... it also says you could do `soup.body.next`. Does that work?

Comment: @Xymostech: `soup.body.next` does the job! Thanks Xymostech

Comment: @ccpizza: Do you just need this to work on your computer, or do you need to distribute it?

Comment: @abarnert: I accept that this is a dup; for some reason that question did not show up when I searched before posting this question; also the accepted answer in that question looks more of a workaround to me; and while `soup.body.next` looks like a better workaround it is still not backword compatible with BS3 but I can live with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want your code to work on everyone's machine, no matter which parser(s) they have installed, etc. (the same `lxml` version built on `libxml2` 2.9 vs. 2.8 acts very differently, the stdlib `html.parser` had some radical changes between 2.7.2 and 2.7.3, …), you pretty much need to handle all of the legitimate results.

If you know you have a fragment, something like this will give you exactly that fragment:

```
soup4 = BeautifulSoup('<div><b>soup 4</b></div>')
if soup4.body:
    return soup4.body.next
elif soup4.html:
    return soup4.html.next
else:
    return soup4
```

Of course if you know your fragment is a single `div`, it's even easier—but it's not as easy to think of a use case where you'd know that:

```
soup4 = BeautifulSoup('<div><b>soup 4</b></div>')
return soup4.div
```

---

If you want to know *why* this happens:

`BeautifulSoup` is intended for parsing HTML documents. An HTML fragment is not a valid document. It's *pretty close* to a document, but that's not good enough to guarantee that you'll get back exactly what you give it.

As [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) says:

> There are also differences between HTML parsers. If you give Beautiful Soup a perfectly-formed HTML document, these differences won’t matter. One parser will be faster than another, but they’ll all give you a data structure that looks exactly like the original HTML document.
>
> But if the document is not perfectly-formed, different parsers will give different results.

So, while this exact difference isn't documented, it's just a special case of something that is.

Comment: Thanks! It is difficult, but I almost managed to convince myself that BS3 did it the wrong way. Or to be more exact, the parser that it relied on (SGML) did it the wrong way. In fact the SGML parser in BS3 was bad enough to occasionally omit entire chunks of markup because of some invalid tag or character, and that was exactly what brought me to BS4 which does a much better job with the same markup.

Comment: Well, the docs are pretty careful to explain that when you give it invalid HTML, you don't really have a right to expect anything specific… just to hope for something useful. So, what BS3 did (in this case) isn't really "wrong", it's just no more right than what all the various parsers with BS4 all do.

Comment: Note that this response is actually broken in case of multiple elements within the body. If you would have `<h1>a</h1><h1>b</h1>` it would only return `<h1>a</h1>`

Comment: @Wolph: True. A fragment that's a single (valid) HTML subtree and a fragment that's a forest of multiple (valid) HTML subtrees are different, and the same parsing code won't necessarily work for both…

Answer (score 1):

As was noted in the old [BeautifulStoneSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML):

> The BeautifulSoup class is full of web-browser-like heuristics for divining the intent of HTML authors. But XML doesn't have a fixed tag set, so those heuristics don't apply. So BeautifulSoup doesn't do XML very well.
>
> Use the BeautifulStoneSoup class to parse XML documents. It's a general class with no special knowledge of any XML dialect and very simple rules about tag nesting...

And in the [BeautifulSoup4 docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#xml):

> There is no longer a BeautifulStoneSoup class for parsing XML. To parse XML you pass in “xml” as the second argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor. For the same reason, the BeautifulSoup constructor no longer recognizes the isHTML argument.

Perhaps that will yield what you want.

Comment: If you actually have perfectly valid X(HT)ML, this will sort of work… but it'll add an `<?xml…?>` to the start, and that's even harder to get around than the `<html><body>` (with or without a `head`).