# Extracting data from HTML bulleted lists in Python

Tags: python, html

I have an html document with the following bulleted list:

```
Body=<ul><li>Preconditions<ul><li>PC1</li><li>PC2</li></ul></li><li>Use Case Triggers<ul><li>T1</li><li>T2</li></ul></li><li>Postconditions<ul><li>PO1</li><li>PO2</li></ul></li></ul>
```

(Alternative View):

- Preconditions

  - PC1
  - PC2
- Use Case Triggers

  - T1
  - T2
- Postconditions

  - PO1
  - PO2

I'm trying to write a function in Python that will disect this list and pull out groups of data. The goal is to put this data in a matrix that would look like the following:

```
[[Preconditions, PC1],[Preconditions, PC2],[Use Case Triggers, T1],[Use Case Triggers, T2],[Postconditions, PO1],[Postconditions,PO2]]
```

The other hurdle to cross is the fact that I need this sort of matrix to generate regardless of the number of ul and li elements.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/24216387/9050514

Comment: Are we to assume that `PC1,.., PO2` are handwritten in HTML, or will they be derived from a function call initiated in JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that takes raw html and deletes all html tags

```
def cleanhtml(raw_html):
    cleanr = re.compile("<.*?>|&([a-z0-9]+|#[0-9]{1,6}|#x[0-9a-f]{1,6});")
    cleantext = re.sub(cleanr, " ", raw_html)
    return cleantext
```

Some other cleanr options:

- `cleanr = re.compile("<[A-Za-z\/][^>]*>")`
- `cleanr = re.compile("<[^>]*>")`
- `cleanr = re.compile("<\/?\w+\s*[^>]*?\/?>")`

But there is a better and easier way with Beautifulsoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def clean_with_soup(url: str) -> str:
    r = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
    return soup.get_text()
```

Answer (score -2):

a good library for parse html - beautifulsoup.  code example:

```
html = "<ul><li>Preconditions<ul><li>PC1</li><li>PC2</li></ul></li><li>Use Case Triggers<ul><li>T1</li><li>T2</li></ul></li><li>Postconditions<ul><li>PO1</li><li>PO2</li></ul></li></ul>"



from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
uls = bs.findAll("ul")
for ul in uls:
    print(ul.findAll("li"))
```