# Python: Can I get the text contents of a div using the div's XPath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the html content of a div using the div's XPath. Is there a way to grab this text and store it in a string using Python? The XPath of the div is `html/body/div[2]/div[3]/ul/li[3]/a`

Comment: No, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465555/can-we-use-xpath-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup innerhtml?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112922/beautifulsoup-innerhtml)

Comment: Show the input you have: either link to the web-site, or the relevant html code. Also, provide the desired output. Thanks.