# Get contents of div by id with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using python2.7.6, urllib2, and BeautifulSoup

to extract html from a website and store in a variable.

How can I show just the html contents of a `div` with an id by using beautifulsoup?

```
<div id='theDiv'>
<p>div content</p>
<p>div stuff</p>
<p>div thing</p>
```

would be

```
<p>div content</p>
<p>div stuff</p>
<p>div thing</p>
```

Answer (score 18):

Join the elements of div tag's [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div id='theDiv'>
    <p>div content</p>
    <p>div stuff</p>
    <p>div thing</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
div = soup.find('div', id='theDiv')
print ''.join(map(str, div.contents))
```

Prints:

```
<p>div content</p>
<p>div stuff</p>
<p>div thing</p>
```

Comment: That appears to work! can you explain what is going on with `print ''.join(map(str, div.contents))`

Comment: @user8028 sure, `contents` actually contains all of the tag's children that can be represented as a string, or as a `Tag` class instance. Applying `map(str, ...)` helps to cast every child to string. Hope that helps.

Comment: i have a special character (€) in the content of the div. how can I encode this to ascii so it is printable to terminal or writable to a file? I always receive error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 1):

Since version 4.0.1 there's a function `decode_contents()`:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<div id='theDiv'>
<p>div content</p>
<p>div stuff</p>
<p>div thing</p>
""")

>>> print(soup.div.decode_contents())

<p>div content</p>
<p>div stuff</p>
<p>div thing</p>
```

More details in a solution to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18602241/237105