# Extract the HTML from between two HTML tags in BeautifulSoup 4.6

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the HTML between two tags with bs4. Is there a way to do javascript's .innerHTML in Beautiful Soup?

This is code that finds a span with the class "title", and gets the text out of it.

```
def get_title(soup):
title = soup.find('span', {'class': 'title'})
return title.text.encode('utf-8')
```

This function incorrectly returns the text of the span without the subscripts. `'Title about H2O and CO2'`

The following code is the result of `title = soup.find('span', {'class': 'title'})`:

```
<span class="title">Title about H<sub>2</sub>O and CO<sub>2</sub></span>
```

How do I get the result without the original span?

Desired result: `'Title about H<sub>2</sub>O and CO<sub>2</sub>'`?

Answer (score 1):

After finding out that JavaScript has .innerHTML, I was able to google the way to do it in beautiful soup. I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112922/beautifulsoup-innerhtml).

After selecting the element with BS4, you can use `.decode_contents(formmater='html')` to get the innerHTML.

```
element.decode_contents(formatter="html")
```