# How to extract an hour from html code with python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am kinda new in Python and beautiful soup.
Can anyone help and answer how can I extract an hour from this html code ?

```
<a class="hour-link fancybox-reservation" href="/47,Lodz/Seans/info/seans/CC527207-4B9C-45CD-812F-3501A647E1B3/dzien/146231/film/16892">12:20</a>
```

Output should be: 12:20

Thank you for all the answers in advance !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup innerhtml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112922/beautifulsoup-innerhtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

>>> data = """<a class="hour-link fancybox-reservation" href="/47,Lodz/Seans/info/seans/CC527207-4B9C-45CD-812F-3501A647E1B3/dzien/146231/film/16892">12:20</a>"""

>>> soup = bs(StringIO(data))
>>> a_tag = soup.find_all('a')

>>> a_tag[0]
<a class="hour-link fancybox-reservation" href="/47,Lodz/Seans/info/seans/CC527207-4B9C-45CD-812F-3501A647E1B3/dzien/146231/film/16892">12:20</a>

>>> a_tag[0].text
'12:20'
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and try to formulate an answer yourself first. I would advise looking at `find_all('a')` and `.text` functionalities for your example.