# how scrape - span aria-hidden="true" - text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, hidden-field

I am trying to web scrape using selenium and beautiful soupe but i cannot get selenium to find the element I need and return the text.

here is the html:

```
<span class="t-14 t-normal">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><!---->Crédit Agricole CIB · Full-time<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->Crédit Agricole CIB · Full-time<!----></span>
          </span>
```

Do you know how to get the text 'Crédit Agricole CIB Full-time' from this html?

I am trying to do something like this:

```
src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')                                    # Now using beautiful soup
intro = soup.find('div', {'class': 'pv-text-details__left-panel'})

text_loc = intro.find( ???? )                                        # Extracting the text
text = text_loc.get_text().strip()                                   # Removing extra blank space
```

I do not know what to put in the ????

Comment: Can you confirm the page url?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't confirm without knowing exactly what the full HTML looks like - there might be other very similarly nested elements before the snippet shared in the question, but if there aren't then you can use `soup.select_one` with the [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) used below:

```py
spanTxt1 = soup.select_one('span.t-14.t-normal span[aria-hidden="true"]')
if spanTxt1 is not None: spanTxt1 = spanTxt1.get_text(strip=True)

spanTxt2 = soup.select_one('span.t-14.t-normal span.visually-hidden')
if spanTxt2 is not None: spanTxt2 = spanTxt2.get_text(strip=True)

print(f' Text1: "{spanTxt1}" \n Text2: "{spanTxt2}" ')
```

should give the output

```markdown
 Text1: "Crédit Agricole CIB · Full-time" 
 Text2: "Crédit Agricole CIB · Full-time"
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

I think the `ember..` section ids are dynamically generated and might be different every time. A more reliable selector for the jobs listed in the experience section might be

```py
expSel = 'div#experience ~ div.pvs-list__outer-container ul.pvs-list li'
```

(It's going for the list *next* to the [empty] `div id="experience"` anchor)

You can even choose a specific experience from the list by changing the end to `li:nth-child(2)` for the second experience, `li:last-child` for the last experience,  `li:nth-last-child(2)` for the *second-to-last* experience,  etc...

You could directly add on to the selector to get the first company:

```py
c1span =  soup.select_one(expSel+' span.t-14.t-normal span')
if c1span is not None:
    print(c1span.get_text(strip=True))
```

and that should print `Crédit Agricole CIB · Full-time`

---

You could also use `expSel` to get *all* the listed experience:

```py
expSelRef = {
    'Position': 'span.mr1.t-bold',  
    'Company+Type': 'span.t-14.t-normal',
    'Dates': 'span.t-14.t-normal.t-black--light', 
    'Location': 'span.t-14.t-normal.t-black--light + span'
}
for e in soup.select(expSel):
    for r in expSelRef:
        eDet = e.select_one(expSelRef[r]+' span[aria-hidden="true"]')
        if eDet is not None: 
            print(f' [ {r}: "{eDet.get_text(strip=True)}" ] ', end='')
    print()
```

output:

```
 [ Position: "Structured Products & Equity Derivatives Sales" ]  [ Company+Type: "Crédit Agricole CIB · Full-time" ]  [ Dates: "Jan 2020 - Present · 2 yrs 10 mos" ]  [ Location: "Paris, Île-de-France, France" ] 
 [ Position: "Equity Sales Trader Assistant" ]  [ Company+Type: "ODDO BHF · Internship" ]  [ Dates: "Jun 2019 - Jan 2020 · 8 mos" ]  [ Location: "Paris, Île-de-France, France" ] 
 [ Position: "Wealth Management Analyst" ]  [ Company+Type: "HSBC · Internship" ]  [ Dates: "Mar 2018 - Sep 2018 · 7 mos" ]  [ Location: "Paris, Île-de-France, France" ] 
 [ Position: "Business Developper" ]  [ Company+Type: "Capgemini · Internship" ]  [ Dates: "Jan 2017 - Aug 2017 · 8 mos" ]
```

Comment: Hi, it works but it returns another 'span text' above, as you expected it to. Do you know how to select the second one? The text I want is exactly the same but the second one.

Comment: The span class above appears to be different from the first one: <span class="mr1 t-bold">
              <span aria-hidden="true"><!---->Structured Products &amp; Equity Derivatives Sales<!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!---->Structured Products &amp; Equity Derivatives Sales<!----></span>
            </span>

Comment: @HugoChikli To print "Structured Products & Equity Derivatives Sales" from the second span, use `print(soup.select_one('.mr1.t-bold').get_text(strip=True))`

Comment: @HugoChikli or did you mean that you're getting "Structured Products & Equity Derivatives Sales" but you don't want to? Because then you might try my answer with `spanTxt2 = soup.select_one('span.t-14.t-normal > span.visually-hidden')` [the added `>` specifies direct descendants (children) only] - can't really tell for sure without seeing full html though

Comment: When I use your code, I get a text from a section a little before on the website that has precisely the same division HTML. The website is a LinkedIn profile page where I wanted to get the information about the experience.

Comment: I want the text from this section <section id="ember941" class="artdeco-card ember-view relative break-words pb3 mt2 " tabindex="-1"><!----> and not ember940

Comment: @HugoChikli try `spanTxt2 = soup.select_one('section#ember941 span.t-14.t-normal > span.visually-hidden')` ?

Comment: I am getting a 'None'

Comment: spanTxt1 = soup.select_one('span.t-14.t-normal span[aria-hidden="true"]')
    if spanTxt1 is not None: spanTxt1 = spanTxt1.get_text(strip=True)

    spanTxt2 = soup.select_one('section#ember941 span.t-14.t-normal span.visually-hidden')
    if spanTxt2 is not None: spanTxt2 = spanTxt2.get_text(strip=True)

    print(f' Text1: "{spanTxt1}" \n Text2: "{spanTxt2}" ')

Comment: Text1: "Thibault’s recent posts and comments will be displayed here." 
 Text2: "None"

Comment: @HugoChikli I can't debug without the actual link/ full html

Comment: here is the link: https://www.linkedin.com/in/thibault-arrighi-a43296130/

Comment: So I want to get the first experience and after ideally the company and start date ! Let me know if you can help

Comment: @HugoChikli please see my edits and let me know if it works. I addeda few more details than asked for; feel free to ignore the second part of my edit

Comment: @HugoChikli ....I do wish you had shared the link earlier - I actually once posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73957068/12652373) about the experience section of LinkedIn which might have helped you

Comment: Yes, it is working now thank you!! I am just not sure what refers to what? So if I want to export this in pandas data frame should I just use expSelRef?

Comment: Hi, don't bother i figured it out !! Big thanks @Driftr95 !! This truly helps