# How to make Beautiful Soup extract text html formatting tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code that runs through my html file to extract text per the html tags,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('b'): 

        text = ''
        for sib in e.next_siblings:
            text += sib.text
```

The problem is this does not include the text formatting tags, i.e. `<font color...></font>, <span></span>, <sup</sup>` etc. in the text, and I require these.

Is there a way to tell beautiful soup to capture all the formatting tags in the siblings?

I have searched "extracting text with formatting" and there doesn't seem to be any information...

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112922/beautifulsoup-innerhtml ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a simple as replacing `sib.text` with `str(sib)`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('b'): 

        text = ''
        for sib in e.next_siblings:
            text += str(sib)
```